# Using SqlServer 2008 in cluster do I need to have Windows in Cluster?

Tags: sql-server, load-balancing

Using SqlServer 2008 in cluster do I need to have the two servers installed with Windows in Cluster mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set up a single node cluster as long as you've got storage that can be shared.  Note, when adding a node to a windows 2008 fail over cluster it will take the clustered resources down, resulting in an outage.

[technet article on windows 2009 failover cluster](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&ved=0CBAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F3%2Fb%2F5%2F3b51a025-7522-4686-aa16-8ae2e536034d%2FOverview%2520of%2520Failover%2520Clustering%2520with%2520Windows%2520Server%25202008.doc&rct=j&q=windows+2008+single+node+cluster&ei=It7gS9vLJozI8wTb1tHGCQ&usg=AFQjCNFB9HYpFC5rkaQDDs5wGZz-ICK3UQ)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179410.aspx) article.

If you are installing on win2k8, you may want to do some checking about possible issues and workarounds.  There are some questions on SF that deal with that.

Comment: For what I read I need the Windows cluster Service, not to have the two windows servers installed in cluster. Is this correct?

Comment: The Windows Cluster Service is used to configure a cluster.  Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189910.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just one note: if you are going to install it on a Windows Server 2008 R2 cluster, you have to slipstream Service Pack 1 into SQL Server 2008 before installing. If you are not familiar with slipstreaming, have a look at the following article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/petersad/archive/2009/06/17/creating-a-merged-slipstreamed-drop-containing-sql-server-2008-rtm-service-pack-1.aspx